# Timer in instantiation method skipped, logical error

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am somewhat new to C# and currently programming a method for instantiating objects in the Unity Editor.

The problem I am having with the code below is a logical error as follows: Instead of objects being created with 10 seconds in between, they are all spawned at the same time.

It is clear to me that this is a logical error. I find this hard to debug because it more so seems that my code for the timer simply isn't running. I've scratched my head as to why, can anyone help an aspiring rookie out? Thanks.

```
 private void CreateObjects(GameObject objectToSpawn, float timer = 0.0f, float timerMax = 10.0f)
{
    //If count of objects is less than the maximum constant, instantiate more at random web positions.
    while (spiderCount < 7)
    {
        //StartCoroutine("SpiderGeneration");
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer >= timerMax)
        {
            //spiderArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("spider");
            //spiderCount = spiderArray.Length;

            Debug.Log("spawnTime is set to true via ObjectGeneration");

            //Generate a random number to choose from a series of set spawn points.
            randPos = Random.Range(1, 4);

            if (randPos == 1)
            {
                //Instantiate(object, position, quat);
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand1, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 1");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (randPos == 2)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand2, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 2");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (randPos == 3)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand3, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 3");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("OBJECT GEN ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright I have figured it out. To anyone reading this that had to same issues as me, my advice is as follows:

So you want a coroutine to start in the update function and not start multiple coroutines every frame, right? You need to set a flag for the coroutine. That was the answer. I simply set a one-time flag to activate upon starting the coroutine that prevents any more from starting until you decide to run it again.

Here is the code.
(Also I wanna say thanks to everyone that helped me out with this! I was able to find the right answer thanks to everyones input :) )

```
using System.Collections;
```

using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class spiderGenerator : MonoBehaviour
{

```
public GameObject player;
public GameObject spiderPrefab;
public GameObject[] spiderArray = new GameObject[7];
public int spiderCount = 0;
private int randPos;
private Vector3 rand1;
private Vector3 rand2;
private Vector3 rand3;

bool inRange = false;
bool spawnerFlag = false;

// Start is called before the first frame update
void Start()
{
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player");
    rand1 = new Vector3(20.49f, 66.671f, 56.98f);
    rand2 = new Vector3(8.88f, 66.671f, 61.65f);
    rand3 = new Vector3(-1f, 66.671f, 65.52f);
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update()
{
    spiderArray = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("spider");
    spiderCount = spiderArray.Length;

    if (player.transform.position.z < 78 && player.transform.position.z > 47 && player.transform.position.x < 25 && player.transform.position.x > -6 && player.transform.position.y < 70 && player.transform.position.y > 60)
    {
        inRange = true;
    }
    else
    {
        inRange = false;
    }


    if (inRange == true && spawnerFlag == false)
    {
        StartCoroutine(CreateObjects(spiderPrefab));
        Debug.Log("Coroutine CreateObjects for {0} STARTED", spiderPrefab);
        spawnerFlag = true;
    }
}

IEnumerator CreateObjects(GameObject objectToSpawn, float timerMax = 10.0f)
{
    

    while (inRange == true && spiderCount < 7)
    {
        yield return new WaitForSeconds(timerMax);
        Debug.Log("spawn for {0} is set to true via ObjectGeneration", objectToSpawn);

        //Generate a random number to choose from a series of set spawn points.
        randPos = Random.Range(1, 4);

        if (randPos == 1)
        {
            //Instantiate(object, position, quat);
            Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand1, transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("SPAWN 1");
        }
        else if (randPos == 2)
        {
            Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand2, transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("SPAWN 2");
        }
        else if (randPos == 3)
        {
            Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand3, transform.rotation);
            Debug.Log("SPAWN 3");
        }
        else
        {
            Debug.Log("OBJECT GEN ERROR");
        }
    }

    Debug.Log("Coroutine TERMINATED");
    yield break;
}
    // need to put everything below the wait for 10 seconds to get results.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this in another way and code it simply using the `Update()` method that Unity calls every frame.

```
private int spiderCount;
private float timer;
public float TimerMax;
public List<Transform> spawnPoints = new List<Transform>(0);

private void Update ( )
{
    timer += Time.deltaTime;
    if ( spiderCount < 7 && timer >= TimerMax )
    {
        if ( spawnPoints.Count == 0 ) { Debug.LogError ( "You don't have any spawn points!" ); return; }
        var spawnPointIndex = UnityEngine.Random.Range ( 0, spawnPoints.Count );
        Instantiate ( objectToSpawn, spawnPoints[spawnPointIndex], transform.rotation );
        ++spiderCount;
        timer = 0;
    }
}
```

Not knowing how you'd like to set up your scene though, you might want ALL 7 spiders to appear straight away, with a 10 second (TimeMax) delay after that? But, either way, this should get you started.

Comment: Hey, I really like what you have going here! Sorry for neglecting some information. I was trying to make the spider spawn one at a time with a 10 second timer in between. I have the SpawnObjects() method in my FixedUpdate() method. I also have the spiderCount automatically set to the number of spider objects currenty in scope before I call the function.            I moved everything over to my Fixed Update and temporarily created new variables in replacement of my parameters. This unfortunately resulted in the same result as before, with all of the spiders spawning at once.

Comment: I am new to stack overflow and am unsure of how to post code in comments?  My updated code looks the same except I combined the while statement condition into the if statement condition just like you had.

Comment: @Eng You won't need to use FixedUpdate here as spawning spiders doesn't have anything to do with the Physics update (I assume).

Comment: @Eng I think you might also be thinking of each method as taking time, and allowing you to pause the execution. It's best to think of methods as being performed 'instantly'. While this is not precisely correct, it doesn't hurt to think of it that way. Hence why you'll need to check the timing within each method.

Answer (score 0):

I believe your issue is that this isn't being run in the update function. I'm fairly certain this would work if you were to call for the method to run in the update function and remove the while loop. This is because the Update() function runs once every frame, so when you add Time.deltaTime to a value, it will always only increase by 1 every second (allowing the timer you have here to work), however, what you have here does not add Time.deltaTime once every frame, it adds it recursively as long as your while(spiderCount < 7) returns true, this causes it to happen a bunch of times on the first frame, because it is reaching the timer value required on that first frame as is adding to the timer many times until it meets the criteria of the while function. This should definitely work if you do the following (also I read that you said you have the method in your FixedUpdate() method, you should only use FixedUpdate for physics updates, rather place it in your Update() method):

```
void Update()
{
     CreateObjects({input the parameters here});
}

private void CreateObjects(GameObject objectToSpawn, float timer = 0.0f, float timerMax = 10.0f)
{
    //If count of objects is less than the maximum constant, instantiate more at random web positions.
    if (spiderCount < 7)
    {
        timer += Time.deltaTime;

        if (timer >= timerMax)
        {
            randPos = Random.Range(1, 4);

            if (randPos == 1)
            {
                //Instantiate(object, position, quat);
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand1, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 1");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (randPos == 2)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand2, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 2");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (randPos == 3)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand3, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 3");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("OBJECT GEN ERROR");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am fairly certain this should work, otherwise you can just use coroutines(which I would personally use), like so:

```
private void Start()
{
      StartCoroutine(CreateObjects({input parameters here}));
}

IEnumerator CreateObjects(GameObject objectToSpawn, float timer = 0.0f, float timerMax = 10.0f)
{
      //Wait for the allotted time amount (in this case 10 seconds)
      yield return new WaitForSeconds(timerMax);

      randPos = Random.Range(1, 4);

            if (randPos == 1)
            {
                //Instantiate(object, position, quat);
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand1, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 1");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (randPos == 2)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand2, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 2");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else if (randPos == 3)
            {
                Instantiate(objectToSpawn, rand3, transform.rotation);
                Debug.Log("SPAWN 3");
                timer = 0.0f;
            }
            else
            {
                Debug.Log("OBJECT GEN ERROR");
            }
       //If the spider count less than required, start the coroutine again to spawn another

       if(spiderCount < 7)
       {
            StartCoroutine(CreateObjects({input parameters here}));
       }
}
```

If you have any questions at all let me know, I am sure this isn't difficult at all to fix, just let me know if you need anything cleared up! (I also apologize if the beginning is a tad confusing to read, I confused myself at first and it shows through haha, but I cleared up when I got to the code)

Comment: Hey! I actually did run my code in the FixedUpdate() function! I called my method in it just you showed, sorry for neglecting to include that!

Comment: I first tried coroutines but was unable to get it functioning, I'll try that approach one more time